# Get GPS Status with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i'm trying find a way to get gps status of my android phone using phonegap.

I can wait until the timeout, but i think that is not the better way.

Somebody know other way?

And sorry my bad english.

Comment: What do you mean by GPS status- your location?  What timeout?  Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this link you will get Help for geolocation/GPS using phonegap

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

This link may be helpful for you...

Comment: really thanks. I see this before, but i dont find a way to get gps status without timeout :(

Comment: are you check in device or emulator??

Comment: i check in device and emulator